# Correct REST usage

Tags: rest

I am struggling a bit with finding out how to stick to correct REST pattern for my problem. I have 2 paths `/User/` and `/Group/` and it self is it fine, but how should I create the path for creating a link from user 1 to group 2 for an example, do I really have to create a new path, `/UserGroups/` for an example for it to be true REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general there is no strict rule defined but its better if you are giving a name which represents your code.